# When to Use Sampling Distributions And When to Use Regular Probability Distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, population

Why/When would it be better to use **Sampling Distributions** such as the **Sampling Distribution of the Sample Mean** and why/when would it be better to use a **Probability Distribution** (such as Beta, Exponential, Gamma, Weibull, etc.) on a certain Data Set?

Here's a **conceptual** example: if I have a Data Set that consists of the following measurements:

> `{0, 0.5, 1, 1, 2, 4}`

Then its Mean is **~1.417** and its SD is also **~1.417**. A good Probability Distribution to fit this Data Set is the **Exponential**, that yields a KS Goodness of Fit test value of 0.173. The PDF for this distribution is:

[Exponential Distribution With L = 0.706 http://www.anony.ws/i/2014/12/10/Exponential07a67.jpg](http://www.anony.ws/i/2014/12/10/Exponential07a67.jpg)

However, I could also use a Sampling Distribution like the Sampling Distribution of the Sample Mean which, according to the Central Limit Theorem, will yield a Normal-like Distribution regardless of the shape of the parent Distribution. Assuming n=4 observations per Sample (N is 6), our expected SD will be **~0.409** (Mean remains the same), giving us the following PDF:

[Normal Distribution With M = 1.417 & SD = 0.409 http://www.anony.ws/i/2014/12/10/Normal.jpg](http://www.anony.ws/i/2014/12/10/Normal.jpg)

*Edit: Yes, the Data Set and Sample Size are too small in practice to apply CLT, but please kindly remember this is just a simple concept example.*

Here, both options seem good for prediction, probability analysis or simulation of the variable, etc. Therefore, why/when should I use one or the other?

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: Statistics is the science of uncertainty. If, as you say, the "Data Set used represents the Entire Population of Events", there is no uncertainty, and you don't need Statistics. You just need accounting.

Comment: Thank you, what you say is correct under some determined assumptions. However, the idea I try to convey with my statement is something more like this: you have logged EVERY event 'X' up to the present moment (the population of events) but you will continue to collect data of 'X' in the future, so there is a degree of uncertainty regarding the future. It is inside this context where I ask if there is any advantage in using sampling distributions.

Comment: If you want to make inferences about future values, *you don't have the population about which you wish to make inferences*.

Comment: Hi Daniel, but then the term "population" is not being used properly. I suggest that you make your question a little more specific.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I will proceed to reformulate my question based on your observations. =)

Comment: I find the question incomprehensible: stripped of distracting phrases, it asks "What are the advantages of modeling sampling distributions when you are able to model a sample distribution?" Since "sampling distribution" and "sample distribution" would seem to be perfect synonyms, there is nothing to be said. Could you clarify whatever distinction you are trying to make?

Comment: I suggest that you omit the "related" questions, which, appear to be anything but.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question again and add a couple of graphs to better ilustrate my point.

Comment: The edited version is much clearer, thank you. But it seems to be addressing two entirely different things: in the first graphic you fit a distribution to the data and in the second graphic you propose that the sampling distribution of the mean can be described by a Normal distribution. Those are two different things with different purposes. (Moreover, the CLT doesn't apply here--not even approximately, because the dataset is too small and skewed.)  It doesn't make sense, then, to ask to compare the "advantages" of two procedures that have entirely different objectives.

Comment: Thank you for keeping on with the comments. Reformulating the question once more, what I want to ask is exactly that: the purposes of each one (I naively used the word 'advantages'). According to what i've read though, CLT applies to any kind of distribution even if it is skewed or irregular, as proved experimentally by this application: http://onlinestatbook.com/stat_sim/sampling_dist/ - As for the size of the Data Set, it's just a concept example.

Comment: The CLT is an *asymptotic* result, so in practice it doesn't actually apply to *anything.* No amount of experimentation can "prove" it.  However, it can be used as an approximation *when the sample size is sufficiently large.*  How large is "sufficient" depends on the underlying population.  Anyway, your latest version of the question appears to be a duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78466. For more like that one, please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22sampling+distribution%22).

Comment: You should definitely take a look at what one of the [simpler versions of the CLT *actually* say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT). It may be very little like what you seem to have been told -- for example, $n=5$ isn't quite the same thing as  $\lim{n\to\infty}\,.$ $\:\:$

Comment: Glen_b, I agree. However please keep in mind this is just a dummy example to clarify the question. Whuber, thank you for the reply. I saw the other question but i think they are not the same since in the other one they explain the difference, but not when its best to apply one or the other.