What is the interpretation of alpha and beta within the plots of a H0 and H1?
Reading about statistical power they draw this:

and say:

Illustration of the power and the significance level of a statistical test, given the null hypothesis (sampling distribution 1) and the alternative hypothesis (sampling distribution 2).

I don't understand how $\alpha$ and $\beta$ relate to the plots. Can you give me some hints please?

Are those Gaussian probability distribution curves (could be any other.) each for a single group of people -say for height, or are they a distribution of the means of many groups of people ? (just taking the mean as an example.)


The term "sampling distribution" refers to the distribution of the test statistic.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78466 for instance.

The graph is correct, but probably more confusing than it is helpful.
The 2 gaussians are meant to represent 2 different scenarios: the first, when $H_0$ is true (sampling distribution 1), the other, when $H_a$ is true (sampling distribution 2).
The term "sampling distribution" is properly used, referring for example to a single mean (for a 1-sample t test), a difference of means (for a 2-sample t-test), or to some other sampling distribution, for any given statistic $t$, which estimates a parameter $\theta$.
In the case of the figure, the null hypothesis is that the parameter in question is $0$ (a common, but not universal situation).
A better figure would be to stack the 2 scenarios as in the figures below:

How alpha and beta relate to the plots should be clearer:

Alpha errors can only occur when $H_0$ is true, while beta errors can only occur when $H_a$ is true
Alpha errors are when you incorrectly reject $H_0$ when it is in fact true (scenario 1), beta errors when you fail to reject $H_0$ when it is in fact false (scenario 2)
If one increases alpha (at the cost of more chances of alpha errors), this will decreases beta (i.e. increase your power)
Similarly, if one decreases alpha, this will increase beta, thus decreasing your power


You risk being misunderstood by referring to the parameter $\theta$ as a "statistic."  I believe this is certain to confuse anyone who isn't already deeply familiar with estimation and hypothesis testing.

I apologize in advance if my suspicions are misplaced: Did you make these plots? Or are you borrowing the plots from someone? If the latter, please add a reference to the source.

ok, i got it finally, at least in broad terms, thank you, that's a master explanation !

dipetkov, this is indeed my graph. @whuber, yes indeed, I misused statistic vs. parameter.; Post has been edited accordingly.
